# VSTO-Custom Task Pane how to get current MailItem

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I want find some way to let custom task pane get current inspector. what method should I use?

I build a VSTO Outlook C# add in by follow this Link:
[Walkthrough: Display custom task panes with email messages in Outlook](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/master/docs/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook.md)

I insert a button on the task pane.
Now I want to use this button to insert a mail title like "test for button" by action Button_Click

I try to use `Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();`

Or`Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;`

to get current inspector but seems not work.

Here is my code below:

```
private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
            if (inspector is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                public Outlook.MailItem mailItem;
                mailItem = inspector as Outlook.MailItem;
                mailItem.subject = "test for button";                
            }                               
        }
```

And I also tried this way:

```
private void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            mailItem.subject = "test for button";
        }
```

The first code `if` judgment is false. And the second code `mailItem=null`;

But my expect output is mailItem equal to the current item where the task pane are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John Hart@GitHub answered my question.
Here is his code below:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Inspector inspector = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector();
        MailItem mailItem = inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
        mailItem.Subject = "test for button";
    }
```

Origin answer see the issue on GitHub:
[VSTO Outlook-Task Pane get Current MailItem](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/issues/2969)

Answer (score 0):

The first code example is wrong - "if (inspector is Outlook.MailItem)" is always false, as inspector is an Inspector object, not a MailItem object.

For the second example, please show all your code - you appear to have a class level Inspector property but it is not clear how that is set. Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveInspector().CurrentItem should work to return a MailItem object, IF it is an email and not another kind of item (you should of course always do a type check).